# Request Facebook access token without being logged in?

Tags: ios, access-token, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to download event information from a company's Facebook page using FacebookSDK 3.1.1 to present in a UITableView. This works fine as long as the user is logged in to his/her Facebook account.

It also works fine if I manually request an access token from developer Facebook and send it along with the Facebook URL request.

Can I request an access token from within the iPhone without being logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I find the facebook developers page a bit difficult to navigate.. Anyway, here is the answer: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/